# Stringtokenizer Issue

Tags: java, string, tokenize

I have the following line:

```
1675 | 29/02/2016 | Jane Smith | James C | James C | 4 | 3
```

Here's my string tokenizer code:

```
 StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, " | ");
 int cId =  Integer.parseInt(stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString());
 String cDate = stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString();
 String cName1 = stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString();
 String cName2 = stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString();
 String cName3 = stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString();
 String cName4 = stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString();
 String wName = stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString();
 String wName2 = stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString();
 String cScore1 = stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString();
 String cScore2 = stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString();
```

However, I keep getting the no such element exception. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem: https://ideone.com/PtxgbP. Are you sure that this is what your line contains?

Comment: The first thing wrong is: you are using StringTokenizer. It has been a legacy class for several versions of Java, and should not be used in any new code. To quote the StringTokenizer api: "StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead."

Comment: Related, from the [documentation for `StringTokenizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html): "_StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code._" If even Oracle tell you not to use it, then don't...

Comment: @Stultuske ha! [Jinx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jinx_(children%27s_game)).

Comment: Your StringTokenizer does not actually use the string `" | "` as a delimiter.  Read the documentation;  the delimiter string you pass to the constructor is the *set of characters* each of which may serve as a delimiter.  So any occurrence of space or bar in the parsed text signals a new token.  Since the delimiter argument is treated as a set, and duplicate characters make no sense, I'm guessing you actually wanted a three-character delimiter instead, which is something StringTokenizer cannot do.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String line = "1675 | 29/02/2016 | Jane Smith | James C | James C | 4 | 3";
String parts[] = line.split(Pattern.quote(" | "));
```

The result is an array of String `parts[0] .. parts[5]`

Check it out with the output `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));`

```
[1675, 29/02/2016, Jane Smith, James C, James C, 4, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using `StringTokenizer` class why dont you use `split();` method of `String` class.

```
String abc ="your | string | should | be | here ";
String[] strArr = abc.split(" | ");
/// loop on strArr to get your tokens.
```